# Use nodemon with docker and docker-compose

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, nodemon

I'm using nodemon with docker-compose.
Here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:10

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY . .

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

My docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services:
  app:
    build: .
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/src/app
      - /usr/src/app/node_modules
    container_name: docker-node-mongo
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
      - 9229:9229
    command: npm start
    links:
      - mongo
      - redis
  mongo:
    container_name: mongo
    image: mongo
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
  redis:
    image: redis:alpine
    volumes:
      - /var/redis/data:/data
```

And my package.json script:

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon --inspect=0.0.0.0 index.js"
  }
}
```

According to the code inside of my working docker container, my code is updating, but I don't have any reload.

Comment: can you ssh into the container and check your package.json?

Comment: @federkun ```{
  "name": "docker-node-mongo",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon --inspect=0.0.0.0 index.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "bluebird": "^3.5.5",
    "body-parser": "^1.18.3",
    "ejs": "^2.6.1",
    "express": "^4.16.3",
    "mongoose": "^5.2.7",
    "nodemon": "^1.19.1",
    "redis": "^2.8.0"
  }
}```

Comment: You have to add `nodemon` as a global in your dockerfile i.e. `run npm install -g nodemon`

Comment: @Intellidroid ```FROM node:10

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install -g nodemon
RUN npm install

COPY . .

CMD ["npm", "start"]``` if you meant this, it doesn't work.

Comment: Did you bring your rebuild it on bringing your docker-compose back up? `docker-compose up --build`

Comment: @Intellidroid Yes, I have rebuilt it.

Comment: have you tried it without the `--inspect` flag? or at least without the value of the `--inspect` flag

Comment: @Intellidroid Yes.

Comment: When you bring your application up can you share the output from the terminal?

Comment: @Intellidroid, everything seems to be ok ```> docker-node-mongo@1.0.0 start /usr/src/app> nodemon index.js[nodemon] 1.19.1[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`[nodemon] watching: *.*[nodemon] starting `node index.js`Server running...MongoDB Connected```

Comment: @Intellidroid Here is a [screenshot](https://imgur.com/ek2Ey8y)

Comment: Bizarre because nodemon is running??? But I guess it is not seeing your changes right....so that can only be down to your volume or dockerfile

Comment: remove `    volumes:
      - .:/usr/src/app
      - /usr/src/app/node_modules` these line from docker compose and `   command: npm start`  as code and command is already part of  docker image

Comment: @Adiii still doesn't work

Comment: btw what is the error you are facing? not loading in browser?

Comment: @Adiii there's no error actually. It just doesn't work. As a test I added console.log in my controller to check nodemon's reloading: ```app.get('/', async (req, res) => {
  console.log('get');
  return res.render('index', { items: await Item.find() });
});``` and the output won't change if I just write something else, only if I restart my container.

Comment: oh so you mean changes not detected in you code?

Comment: @Adiii yes. And the main point is that in my code in docker container files it is changing,but it doesn't reload.

Comment: change the command in package.json to `nodemon --watch directory_to_watch server.js`

Comment: I've spent hours trying to figure out the problem, and in my case it was nodemon.json, with the line
```
"ignore": ["_filenames_or_directory_"]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue with nodemon with `inspect` on restart. You can read more about the issue [here](https://github.com/remy/nodemon/issues/1050). You can try the work around mentioned by nodemon team

```
"inspect": "kill-port --port 9229 && node --inspect=0.0.0.0:9229 build/startup.js",
"start_watch_inspect": "nodemon --delay 80ms --watch build/ build/startup.js --exec 'npm run inspect'",
```

You can make it working using below command if you can manage without inspect

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon index.js"
  }
```

This will work with mounting the directory
`docker run --rm -v /home/myapp:/root  --name test -it testnode`

OR

copy code to docker build and update file inside the container will also work fine.

[image]

Answer (score 13):

If you start nodemon with the `-L` or `--legacy-watch` flag, it will restart correctly when changes are detected. The script in your `package.json` file would be:

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon -L --inspect=0.0.0.0 index.js"
  }
}
```

I came across this solution as a comment on this gist:
https://gist.github.com/ksmithut/e126f7ddb40b760487a17e8b569a77b5#gistcomment-2725750

This can be found in the official documentation at https://github.com/remy/nodemon#application-isnt-restarting

Answer (score 0):

Following what I did on my environment.
I hope this help someone.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with the same issue for years(ish), tried all possible permutations of hacks and finally, a few months back docker-compose started to support watch mode natively. You can read more about it [here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/file-watch/).

In short, you can declare your service in docker-compose similar to this:

```yaml
api:
   build: .
   develop:
       watch:
           - action: sync
             path: ./src
             target: /app/src
                 ignore:
                     - .git
                     - node_modules
           - action: rebuild
                 path: package.json
       ports:
            - 3000:3000
```

In this configuration we specify custom options for watch:

- action `sync` will copy the file changed in `path` to the `target`. Ignore ensures `.git` and `node_modules` is not watched.

In some cases (like adding dependencies) you might want to rebuild the entire container since copy-pasting is not enough. For this scenario you can use action `rebuild`.

- action `rebuild` will use changes to a provided `path` to trigger container rebuild process.

Hope this helps!