# How to use nodemon with docker while running docker on windows?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have seen this [question and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57573992/use-nodemon-with-docker-and-docker-compose) and other questions and answers but none seems to answer the question: How to use nodemon with docker while running docker **on windows**?.

So after a few hours of research and finding a solution I have decided to post the question and answer to help anyone looking for the same solution in the future.

Comment: I’m not clear from reading this what your actual question is.  If you have another answer to the question you linked to you’re certainly welcome to add it, even if it already has an accepted answer.

Comment: I know but my question also addresses the issue while running docker on a windows machine. It is actually a new question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How to use nodemon with docker while running docker on windows?

**Short answer:** use `nodemon -L index.js`

**Long answer:** Thanks to this article: [Getting started with Docker for local Node.js development](https://medium.com/@francoisromain/getting-started-with-docker-for-local-node-js-development-192ceca18781) and this [response](https://medium.com/@yonatan.kr/great-article-985ed04651c6) I was able to figure out how to do it.

For addition reading to understand why we use `nodemon` with `-L` see [this section of the nodemon docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nodemon?source=post_page---------------------------#application-isnt-restarting).